# fatal error: linux/kthread.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu, kernel

I'm trying to get familiar with kthreads and have written a very simple program to test it in  C, with guidance from: http://tuxthink.blogspot.com/2011/02/kernel-thread-creation-1.html. I'm running Ubuntu in VMware on MacOSX.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cycle.h"
#include <linux/kthread.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>

int main(){
    static struct task_struct *kthread;

    thread1 = kthread_create(thread_fn, NULL, "thread1");
    wake_up_process(thread1);
    kthread_stop(thread1);

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this using gcc (gcc test5.c -o test5.out) I get "fatal error: linux/kthread.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated."

When I go to look in /usr/include/linux/ there is no kthread.h file, so it seems reasonable. When I search for kthread.h i find one in /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-31/include/linux and one in /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-29/include/linux but I just keep getting for error messages after I tried to copy one of them to /usr/include/linux/:

```
In file included from /usr/include/linux/kthread.h:4:0,
             from test5.c:5:
/usr/include/linux/err.h:22:35: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’     before ‘ERR_PTR’
/usr/include/linux/err.h:27:33: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘PTR_ERR’
/usr/include/linux/err.h:32:33: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’     before ‘IS_ERR’
/usr/include/linux/err.h:37:33: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘IS_ERR_OR_NULL’
/usr/include/linux/err.h:49:35: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘ERR_CAST’
/usr/include/linux/err.h:55:32: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘PTR_RET’
In file included from test5.c:5:0:
/usr/include/linux/kthread.h:7:10: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/linux/kthread.h:7:13: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/linux/kthread.h:58:2: error: unknown type name ‘spinlock_t’
/usr/include/linux/kthread.h:59:19: error: field ‘work_list’ has incomplete type
/usr/include/linux/kthread.h:64:19: error: field ‘node’ has incomplete type
/usr/include/linux/kthread.h:66:2: error: unknown type name ‘wait_queue_head_t’
/usr/include/linux/kthread.h:67:2: error: unknown type name ‘atomic_t’
/usr/include/linux/kthread.h:128:1: error: unknown type name ‘bool’
test5.c: In function ‘main’:
test5.c:11:2: error: ‘thread1’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test5.c:11:2: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
test5.c:11:12: error: ‘thread_fn’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Any idea of how to solve this would be very much appreciated!

Comment: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers` or a package witha similar name

Comment: @H2CO3 I don't think that will solve the problem, as I think that's user-space code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are *kernel threads* meant to be used in the **kernel-space** and not **user-space** threads ! you should either change your code to a kernel module with a proper Makefile or use [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) for user-space threads. Maybe you should start with [HelloWorld](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/c147.htm) kernel module

Comment: Thank you! The guide was useful. Unfortunately I had some problems with the suggested Makefile used by the author, but the Makefile from the guide I originally followed worked fine.